Can you define a topology so that all the parametrically definable subsets are open?
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first order language with only relation and constant symbols.  Suppose $\mathfrak{A}=\langle A,\ldots\rangle$ is a structure for $\mathcal{L}$. Let $\mathscr{D}$ be the set of all parametrically definable subsets of $A$ by formulas of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$. Here are my questions.

Can we define a topology on $A$ so that all the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ are compact?
Can we define a topology on $A$ such that all the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ are open?
I understand the following (I think), please correct me if I'm wrong. Let $X\subseteq A$ be open if and only if $X\in\mathscr{D}$. We may choose an infinitary language $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\lambda}$ depending on the cardinality of $A$. The reason for this is to deal with arbitrary unions of open subsets of $A$. We want to take a sufficiently long disjunction of formulas to show that an arbitrary union of open subsets is open (right?).
What if we restrict to a nice fragment of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1\omega}$? Can we circumvent the problem in (3)?
What if we relax the defining condition of $\mathscr{D}$ to allow only $\mathcal{L}_{\omega\omega}$-formulas?

I'm mainly looking for some references. Your help is deeply appreciated.

I'm not sure 1 and 2 are really the questions you want to ask, since they admit trivial answers. For 1, if $A$ is any set, the trivial topology (in which the open sets are $\varnothing$ and $A$) has the property that every set is compact. In particular all the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ are compact. For 2, if $A$ is any set, take the discrete topology, in which every set is open. In particular all the elements of $\mathscr{D}$ are open.

Another way that question 2 trivializes: For any $a\in A$, the singleton set ${a}$ is always parametrically definable by the formula $x = a$. If $\tau$ is a topology with the property that every parametrically definable set is open, then all singletons are open, so $\tau$ is the discrete topology (since every set is a union of singletons).

@AlexKruckman I see, thanks! What if I wanted to make only the definable sets compact; actually, I meant to ask (1), with that in mind. Sorry, I missed it.

Not an answer but too long for a comment:
As Alex Kruckman observed, once every parameterically-definable set is open we have the discrete topology. That said, there are a couple possible ways around this.
Most immediately, we could look for a family of topologies: to each set $X\subseteq A$, let $\tau^\mathfrak{A}_X$ be the topology on $A$ generated by the sets definable with parameters from $X$; or, if you prefer, the sets which are definable-without-parameters in the sense of the expansion $\mathfrak{A}_X:=(A;..., X)$. On the one hand this avoids triviality (consider $\tau_\emptyset^\mathfrak{A}$) but on the other hand lets us incorporate parameters as desired. There are meaningful questions we can ask about these families of topologies, see e.g. these questions of mine 1, 2.
Another option, which I actually think is more serious but significantly trickier, is to change what our points are. A point in the sense of $\mathfrak{A}$ shouldn't be an element of $\mathfrak{A}$ but rather a subset of (or relation/function on) $\mathfrak{A}$. Letting $U$ be a new unary relation symbol, we get from $\mathfrak{A}=(A;...)$ a topology on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ generated by sets of the form $$\{B\subseteq A: \mathfrak{A}_B\models\varphi\}$$ for $\varphi$ a formula (with parameters!) in the language of $\mathfrak{A}$ together with the new symbol $U$. Here $\mathfrak{A}_B$ is the expansion of $\mathfrak{A}$ gotten by interpreting $U$ as $B$. This is an extremely fruitful trick but even basic questions get very difficult; see, for example, the theory of inductive definitions.

Thanks, Noah!!!
